# How to have android ICS components on non ICS android device

Tags: java, android

is there anyway to get the android ICS controls on non ICS android phones in apps ? I have seen for example echofone or some other apps using ICS controls and these apps run fine on lower versions than ICS (4.0), is there any way except any third party library ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Action Bar Sherlock can solve your problem:

http://actionbarsherlock.com/

You can see some examples here:

https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/tree/master/samples/demos/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/demos

Answer (score 1):

[HoloEverywhere](https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere) should do the trick for you:

> Bringing Holo Theme from Android 4.1 to 2.1 and above.

Doing this without third party libraries would force you to reimplement all the controls by yourself. Not a clever thing to do.

But you may get your resources [here](http://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html) if you really want to do it from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use HoloEverywhere then you could use http://android-holo-colors.com.
It generates holo widgets and styles for you.